# Docker compose error for simple Angular app (with nginx and node images)

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Its a simple angular app requiring docker with node and nginx, to learn the basics of Docker Compose and DockerFile.

**Tech Stack / Information:**

- Hello world Angular CLI APP (very light / used for docker demo).
- Docker (using node and nginx).
- Docker Desktop.
- Angular 16.

**DockerFile: for Node**

```
# Stage 1: Node Image
FROM node:alpine AS node
WORKDIR /app

COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build --prod
```

**DockerFile: for Nginx**

```
# Stage 2: Nginx Image
FROM nginx:alpine AS nginx
COPY --from=node /app/dist/my-first-angular /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
```

**Docker Compose Yml File:**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  node:
    build:
      context: ./node
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
    depends_on:
      - node
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail http://localhost || exit 1
      interval: 60s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 20s
      timeout: 10s
    command: "npm install && ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200"
```

**Error:**

The build seems to fail. Looks like it cant find the package file.
How do I resolve this issue?

> ERROR [node 4/5] RUN npm install

[image]

**Folder structure:**

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why you're `command` line is failing in the yml file but you could try moving it to the end of your dockerfile, using `CMD`. using `depends_on` in your yml so that the frontend service runs last might be necessary as well

Comment: @willwrighteng could you provide an example please

Comment: I've updated my attempt to have 2 images. One for nginx and one for node

Answer (score 2):

In your Dockerfile you use a Node image to build your code, then you copy the result of the build in a Nginx image.  The latter image  (the one you run with Compose!) simply does not contain Node.  If you want to run a single image containing both Node and Nginx you have two options:

1. install Node in Nginx, or
2. install Nginx in Node.

A better approach would be having two containers, one for Nginx and one for Node.  A simple search for something like "Docker Nginx with Node" will give you a lot of examples.

Comment: Thanks @Pino could you update the example in my question to show what you mean please